# Keyboard shortcut to expand all the package tree folders (project view) in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there way to expand all folders of the project view in Android Studio 1.5.1 ? At this point I have to use the right arrow to expand the whole tree.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Sorry to reopen, but I've found a way to currently solve the asked question.

You can press the star (asterisk) '*' key of your numeric keyboard in the root of your tree so much times as you need expand subfolders in the hierarchy (for example, if you have three sub-levels, press three times the '*' key in your numeric keyboard with the root folder selected).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there isn't a way to do that, but if you're trying to find something in the project hierarchy, you can use the shortcut `CMD`+`Shift`+`O` and just start typing.

[image]

Note that it also does a fuzzy search

[image]